# WSO2 API endpoint options

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When creating an API in WSO2, the wizard has a section to pick an endpoint - current selection choices include: HTTP Endpoint, Address Endpoint, failover endpoint, Load Balance.  Can additional endpoints be added, such as FTP?  Is there code / config that can be added for an FTP endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager don't support FTP protocol, you can [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) to do the same. You refer these samples [here](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/01/wso2-esb-example-file-exchanging-hub-part-1/) and [here](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/01/sftp-file-transfer-wso2-esb/)